# Export Panels Node Template Variants to Panel Pages

Tags: drupal

I am trying to export all of the panel node template variants to panel pages in Drupal 7.  So far I have not had much luck because the code is not exactly the same.  Does anyone know of a good way to do this or should I just try configuring the code I get from the variant export to match the panel page code needed for import?  I rather not do it that way because I have over 100 variants to export to panel pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the Ctools bulk exporter you can select any of the variants you like all at once and export them into a module (kind of like Features). Then i would guess you need to have that module enabled forever to use these variants on your other site. Yes, annoying that you can't simply export the entire panel page.